# Scala Compile-time checking of object using quoted.Type

Tags: scala, match, compile-time, scala-3

I have a Scala 3 class whose instances contain a quoted.Type object to capture the type of the instance:

```scala
class Skey[T](val name: Symbol)(using val qt: quoted.Type[T])
```

The whole point of having `qt` there is to verify that the `Skey` is of the right type, but, in a typical case, where I have a function that wants to return a retrieved `Skey`, represented schematically thus (edited since original post):

```
class SkeyIndex(...):
  private var hMap = immutable.HashMap[String, Skey[?]]:
  ...
  def lookup(y: Skey[T], ...): Option[Skey[T]] =
    val existing: Option[Skey[?]] = hMap.get(name)
    existing match 
      case None => None
      case x @ Skey[?] => 
         if x.qt == y.qt then x // THIS IS NOT QUITE RIGHT!
         else ...
```

the equality test verifies that `x` is indeed of the correct type, but at run time. Is there a `quoted.Type` match idiom or some magic involving [match types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html) that will allow the compiler to infer that x is an `Skey[T]` and not some other sort of `Skey`?

I'm sure there's no way to do this in Scala 2, but I have my fingers crossed for Scala 3, which has a cleaner treatment of type-level programming.

Comment: I realize I can write `if x.qt == y.qt then Skey[T](x.name)(using y.qt)` but this is ugly and pointless, since the object will be `==` to `x` except for type.

Comment: That very much depends on where that `x` is coming from. If it is dynamically created at runtime in a way that it can be `Skey[T]` or some other `Skey[A]` based on some run time value, then no, you can not verify its type at compile time.

Comment: @sarveshseri: I've edited the question to be more faithful to what I actually want, which is to check the type of an entity retrieve from a Map.